# Nodejs require a module in async way

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to load 2 modules in async way because i have few problems.

1. The first module loads and create a database connection (that takes
   a while)
2. The second module take the created connection to make sessions using express-sessions.

The problem is the 2nd module is loaded before the first one.

This is the code of Module 1

```js
const sequelize = require('sequelize');
const chalk = require('chalk');
const mysql2 = require('mysql2/promise');

// Lettura variabili dal file di configurazione .env
const DATABASE_USER = process.env.DATABASE_USER;
const DATABASE_PASSWORD = process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD;
const DATABASE_NAME = process.env.DATABASE_NAME;
const DATABASE_URL = process.env.DATABASE_URL;
const DATABASE_PORT = process.env.DATABASE_PORT;
const DATABASE_DIALECT = process.env.DATABASE_DIALECT;

// Connessione al database
let connectionSequelize;

// Connessione al DBMS
mysql2.createConnection({ user: DATABASE_USER, password: DATABASE_PASSWORD }).then((connection) => {
    // Connessione al DBMS completata
    // Creo il database se non esiste
    connection.query(`CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ${DATABASE_NAME}`).then(() => {
        // Database creato, elimino la connessione con mysql2 e creo un instanza di sequelize che diventerà la connessione in tutto l'applicativo
        connection.close();
        connectionSequelize = new sequelize(DATABASE_NAME, DATABASE_USER, DATABASE_PASSWORD, { host: DATABASE_URL, dialect: DATABASE_DIALECT, port: DATABASE_PORT, operatorsAliases: false });

        // Verifico che la connessione al database sia stata eseguita correttamente
        connectionSequelize.authenticate().then(() => {
            // Connessione eseguita correttamente
            console.log(`${chalk.green('✓')} Connessione al database ${chalk.green(DATABASE_NAME.toUpperCase())} effettuata.`);

            // Esporto la connessione che verrà utilizzata in tutta l'applicazione
            module.exports = { connectionSequelize }
        }).catch(error => {
            // Connessione al database fallita, visualizza errore e termina il processo
            console.log(`${chalk.red('✗')} Impossibile connettersi al database ${chalk.green(DATABASE_NAME.toUpperCase())}`);
            process.exit();
        })
    }).catch(error => { throw (error); })
}).catch(error => {
    // Connessione al database fallita, visualizza errore e termina il processo
    console.log(`${chalk.red('✗')} Impossibile connettersi al database ${chalk.green(DATABASE_NAME.toUpperCase())} con mysql2`);
    process.exit();
});
```

Code of Module 2:

```js
const expressSession = require('express-session');
const MySQLStore = require('connect-session-sequelize')(expressSession.Store);
const connectionSequelize = require('./database').connectionSequelize

module.exports = server => {

    console.log('in')

    // Impostazioni caricate dal file di configurazione
    const SESSION_SECRET_KEY = process.env.SESSION_SECRET_KEY;
    const SESSION_MAXAGE_COOKIE = process.env.SESSION_MAXAGE_COOKIE;
    const SESSION_DATABASE_TABLE = process.env.SESSION_DATABASE_TABLE;
    const SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = process.env.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME;

    server.use(expressSession({
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        secret: SESSION_SECRET_KEY,
        cookie: {
            maxAge: SESSION_MAXAGE_COOKIE,
            httpOnly: true
        }
    }));

}
```

And the main server.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config();
const chalk = require('chalk');

// Istanza express
const server = express();

// Caricamento file di configurazione server
require('./config/database');
require('./config/session')(server);

// Impostazioni da file .env
const SERVER_PORT = process.env.SERVER_PORT

// Avvia il server sulla porta selezionata nel file di configurazione
server.listen(SERVER_PORT, () => {
    console.log(`${chalk.green('✓')} Server disponibile all'indirizzo ${chalk.green(process.env.SERVER_URL + ':' + process.env.SERVER_PORT)}.`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well,
you need to make the second module, wait for the first one
or load the second module only after the first one is loaded .

The most direct way to do it on your code is to pass module 1 the server object:

then you can do this from inside module 1.
require('./session')(server)

You can also write module 1 in a way which return the promise and then:

```
return mysql2
  .createConnection({})
  .then(db = > {
     const connectionSeqalize  = ....
     return Promise.resolve(connectionSeqalize)
   })
```

Then from server.js or module 2,

`require('database').then(connectionSeqalize => {})`

I would suggest refactor so the sql module , setup the middlewere on server
which will save you from adding extra logic for async modules loading .

Comment: So you suggest to load the module on the server.js? Bevande in the future my idea is to like 5 configuration files (db,sessions,sequelize relations and server middlewares) which are all modules imported inside server.js. In this way i have a separated config files Logic

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean .
You can always require the module several times with different configurations
and each time (different db, different express server, etc)

Comment: and please consider , even if you use 10 different databases , 
you will **still** use only one db for the sessions .

Comment: yeah yeah i have created the module for the database connection for a main reason, create an instance of sequelize (which is a connection to the database) to share over all the application using the modules.

Comment: Okay , so what else is missing from my answer ? I'm not sure .

Answer (score 0):

You could add the requirement, after the connection creates, inside the `.then(connection => REQUIRE_HERE)`